# Get cookie not listed in docuement.cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I need to copy value of auhorization cookie (name FedAuth and FedAuth1).
I have a problem with this, because it is not listed in document.cookie. It is present in Resources tab in Chrome Developer Tools. However I cannot copy this, because there is no such an option, also Ctrl+C isn't working.

How can I copy, save to file or retrieve in any way this cookie?

Comment: Is your Cookie Http-Only? (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly)

Comment: Yes, it has HTTP flag

Comment: Then, there's no chance to get it using JavaScript (that's the basic idea behind HttpOnly) and see the answers below.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But this don't have to be from JS, I just want copy this cookie in any way, but Chrome Dev Tools don't have this option

Comment: How about copy to cURL and re-request using the terminal or you set up a local proxy using Gatling recorder http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/http/recorder.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the cookie has the `HttpOnly` flag set, so you can't access that via JavaScript.

[image]

The only way to get that cookie is by using a server side script on the same domain of the cookie. This is a security feature.

Comment: Yup, it has HTTP flag. I checked that I can copy that cookie from Firebug, but I don't want force people, who will copy this cookie, to install this.
Is there any way to enable copying in Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: No. Client-side javascript can't access that, only browser extensions can. Otherwise you'll defeat the purpose of that flag. Maybe you should give us some information of what you want to do, maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Oh, it's complicated. I'm doing LoadRunner Performance Testes and the only way I figured how to authenticate is setting auth cookies. Maybe there is better way, but I don't know any ;)

Comment: So you are generating an HTTP request on another machine using a cookie from the user browser. `HttpOnly` was designed to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

The chances are that although they are listed in Chrome's Developer tools these cookies are [HttpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly). Unfortunately there is no way to access these cookies from JavaScript.